# Get CART checkout time

Tags: ce-1.4.0.1

We build some JSON from cart info and send it to Oracle for processing in our ERP.
Can I get the checkout time of the cart from Magento session?

Looking at getCreatedAt() but not sure what model to get it from.

Comment: Do you want cart time or time when order place? it's possible customer add product to cart but not purchase now. so cart time and checkout time will be different.

Comment: checkout time, please

Comment: I posted answer below. Please check if it's help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get order date and time from sales order model. You can use  below syntax to get date and time.

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($ORDERID);    
$order->getCreatedAt();
```

$ORDERID will be order id to which orders date you want.